# Use FontAwesome icon inside a ::before pseudo element with attr()

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to insert a FontAwesome icon inside a `::before` pseudo element with `attr()` . The original code is more complex, however this will give you an idea of what I want:

```
<div data-background-icon="\f086"></div>

div::before {
  content: attr(data-background-icon);
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grutcop8/

It doesn't work, while the usual way to embed it works OK:

```
div::before {
  content: "\f086";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: Your reference to the data seems to be correct: https://jsfiddle.net/76v9e2ur/

Comment: @timo It is, however it doesn't show the icon.

Comment: A more complicated way would be to have a class which has content:'\f086' and add that class to an element, only if that element has "data-..." == "\\f086". Woof, better not think about it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try with Unicode

CSS escape sequences only work within CSS strings. When you take a CSS escape sequence from an HTML attribute (i.e. outside of CSS), it will be read literally, not interpreted as part of a CSS string.

> If you want to encode the character within an HTML attribute, you need
>   to encode it as an HTML entity.

you should add `"&#x"` before your font-Awesome icon code. ie, if you want to use `/f086`, then write `&#xf086` instead

get the unicode from here - https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

**UPDATE**

If you are using fontAwesome 5, change `font-family: "FontAwesome";` to `font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';`

```css
div:before {
  content: attr(data-background-icon);
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div data-background-icon='&#xf086;'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, it's not really W3C valid, am I right?

Comment: yup. It will give a warning like this - " Document uses the Unicode Private Use Area(s), which should not be used in publicly exchanged documents. (Charmod C073)"

Comment: @DaVoDHoseiny You might have using fontAwesome5. in that case, refer this - https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/nfgp8e0a/1/

Answer (score 2):

CSS reads `\f086` as a string and not as an escape sequence. The fix is either to use it directly inside content attribute like `content: '\f086';` or directly copying and pasting icon in HTML attribute (make sure you save your file as UTF-8)

HTML:

```
<div data-background-icon=""></div> <!-- this is the bluetooth icon copied from fontawesome -->
```

CSS:

```
div::before {
  content: attr(data-background-icon);
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

OR make use of HTML entities:

HTML:

```
<div data-background-icon="&#xf086;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div::before {
  content: attr(data-background-icon);
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76v9e2ur/1/

Comment: Note that if using Font Awesome 5, the font family has changed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004111/83542