# The "before" pseudo element not working in Font awesome v.5

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

li.facebook:before {
  content: "\f09a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li class="facebook">123 Drive.</li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> Twitter</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Related question if you are using the JS+SVG version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48753688/8620333

Comment: Related question dealing with **font-weight** issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754892/8620333

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**UPDATE 3:**

The `font-family` is wrong.

use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"`

And maybe you have to set a `font-weight` see [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#define)

**UPDATE 2: [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR)**

The `font-family` is wrong.

use `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"`

---

For [Font Awesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css#pseudo-elements) this must be one of the following:

**Updated because you use css webfonts:**

For method Web Fonts with CSS

**Free**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
```

**Pro**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"
```

**Brands** => use this!

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nwodoo32/1/

---

For method SVG with Javascript

**Solid**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid"
```

**Regular**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Regular"
```

**Brands**

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
```

**Light** (Pro)

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Light"
```

Comment: it works fine anywhere else but in codepen.io, be aware.

Comment: "font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" did not work until I added "font-weight: 900;"

Comment: Something else to consider: some times if you don't assign a `font-weight` it won't show. Try from 100 to 900.

Comment: When all else fails, read the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) on pseudo elements. Their website lists out a table with font name, weight, etc. for each style.

Answer (score 15):

You must change your font family and also you must define font weight.

```
<ul>
<li class="facebook"> Facebook</li>
<li><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> Twitter</li>
</ul>

li.facebook:before {
    content: "\f09a";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"; /* change like this */
    font-weight: 900; /* insert this definition */
}
li {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";`


As he wants the facebook logo which is in the Brands pack your `font-family` is **wrong** - see my answer.

And yes he **could** (not must) add `font-weight`, but that was not what he asked

Comment: Would've never thought that `font-weight` can be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for reminding the `font-weight`!

Answer (score 4):

You also need to enable the Pseudo elements if you want to use the font with :before or :after CSS selectors..

```
<script>
   window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
      searchPseudoElements: true
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, but is important to note this config **must be set before** importing/linking/budling the `fontawesome-free or pro` JS file.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** - Register script for pseudo element on dom ready

```
window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
}
```

**Step 2** - Use font-awesome 5 font family like below (Use font-weight above 600 for free)

```
.class:before{
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 600;
    content: "\f105";
}
```