# Font Awesome 5 shows empty square when using the JS+SVG version

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Attempting to replace the bullet type on an list item tag with a Font Awesome icon but I am getting an empty square:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.testitems {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.testitems:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f058";
  margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
  color: #004d00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I know the font library is loading because I was able to use `<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i><li class="testitems">List Item 1</li>` and the font rendered properly (though not styled properly).

Comment: Yup!  Loading the JS version.  Will DL the CSS version and give it a go.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Temani - not sure what you mean by the last comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sup>If you are using the **CSS version** read this: [Font Awesome 5, why css content is not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49690006/8620333)</sup>

Using the last release of the Font Awesome 5 you can enable the use of pseudo-element with the JS version by adding `data-search-pseudo-elements` like below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.testitems {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.testitems:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f058";
  display:none; /* We need to hide the pseudo element*/
}
/*target the svg for styling*/
.testitems svg {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<script data-search-pseudo-elements src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 5</li>
</ul>
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

You can check the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#with-svg-js) for more details :

> If you’re using our SVG + JS framework to render icons, you need to do a few extra things:
>
> **Enable Pseudo Elements**
>
> Using CSS Pseudo elements to render icons is disabled by default when using our SVG + JS Framework. You’ll need to add the `<script data-search-pseudo-elements ... >` attribute to the `<script />` element that calls Font Awesome.
>
> **Set Pseudo Elements’ display to none**
>
> Since our JS will find each icon reference (using your pseudo element styling) and insert an icon into your page’s DOM automatically, we’ll need to hide the real CSS-created pseudo element that’s rendered.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) of how to enable Pseudo class...

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.testitems {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.testitems::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
  content: "\f058";
  display: none;
}
.user::before{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
  content: "\f007";
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script>FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };</script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="testitems">List Item 5</li>
</ul>
<i class="fa fa-user"></i><br>
<a class="user" href="#">User</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install fontawesome in your project using a package manager (I'm using yarn on a Rails project), you have to import not only the js resource but also the css resource:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all"
```