# Font Awesome through CDN does not show required icon

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to use Awesome icons in a Laravel/Vue project. But for some reason the icon doesn't show properly, whatever I try.

I now tried the most simple thing with Awesome I could imaging: a simple HTML-page using a CDN. The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </header>

    <body>
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, like in my Laravel project, I am not seeing the camera icon, but some kind of dummy icon: a rectangle with F030 in it.

BTW: I run a Xampp stack under Windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need the V5, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690376/8620333

Comment: Your `<head>` is not closed, and there is some bogus `<header>` instead.

Comment: Using <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css"> solved the problem. Thnx.

Comment: you can then accept the duplicate provided by clicking on the button in top banner

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    </header>

    <body>
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just edited the link with a cdn link from the font-awesome page
, whatever you embed does not include your desired icon

taken from [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont#load-all-styles)