# Use icon in sentence via CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to use icon in css file.

For example like this, there shows R.

```
.playlist .controls label.stereopan:after {
  content: "R";
}
```

So, I did like this below.

```
.playlist .controls label.stereopan:before {
  content: '<i class="fas fa-car"></i>';
}
```

However it doesn't work, the tag is not parsed and just show the sentence.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: use font awesome correctly by checking their doc. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690376/8620333

Comment: and to find the unicode value https://fontawesome.com/icons/car?s=solid , here it is `f1b9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Car font link : https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/car?s=solid
you need add this code with font-family according your current fontawesome version :

```
  .playlist .controls label.stereopan:before {
    content: '\f1b9'; 
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    }
```

Comment: font-family works well for me , thank you very much!!