# Font Awesome 5 unicode

Tags: css, unicode, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Font Awesome 5 star icon has `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` and `<i class="far fa-star"></i>` different is `fas , far` and Unicode for both is `f005` now i want to use it as my rating system where first is regular star and by click become solid star, but how do I define this `fas` `far` in my css?

## Code

```
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
              content: '\f005';
              color: #e74c3c;
              transition: all .25s;
              font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
              font-weight: 900;
}


label.star:before {
          content: '\f005';
          font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
          font-weight: 900;
}
```

with my codes above i only get solid star

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<sup>If you are using the **JS+SVG version** read this: [Font Awesome 5 shows empty square when using the JS+SVG version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48753688/8620333)</sup>

The difference between the **regular** and the **solid** version is the `font-weight`. You simply need to adjust this one to swap between both version:

```css
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #e74c3c;
  transition: all .25s;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}

label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<input type="checkbox" class="star">
<label class="star"></label>
```

Here is another related question [Font Awesome 5 on pseudo elements shows square instead of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754892/font-awesome-shows-square-instead-of-icon-when-used-directly-in-css/49755090#49755090) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what type of star you wanted when in inactive/default state, so guessed that you needed the hollow star. You can change the appearance of FA5 icons dramatically by changing the `font-weight` to and from `400` or `900`. I placed stars by the important comments in the demo. The remaining changes are just optional miscellaneous styles like `text-shadows`, 2 way `transition`s on `:hover`, etc. Although optional, you should try hiding the actual checkbox and just use the label, it's better aesthetically IMO.

### Demo

```css
input.star {
  /*⭐} By using the label as the interface (button) this can be hidden*/
  display: none;
}

.star {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  text-shadow: .25px -.25px 1px #000;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.star:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-shadow: -5px -6px 4px rgba(255, 142, 86, 0.6);
}

input.star:checked~label.star:hover {
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-shadow: -5px -6px 4px rgba(255, 142, 86, 0.6);
}

label.star::before {
  content: "\f005";
  /*⭐} Optional but recommended */
  color: #e74c3c;
  transition: all .25s;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  /*⭐} By lowering the font-weight, the icon is an outline */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 32px;
}

input.star:checked~label.star::before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #e74c3c;
  transition: all .25s;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!------------{} Follow this pattern so that the label acts as a
------------------ remote button to the hidden checkbox-->

<!--⭐} Set an #id on checkbox-->
<input id='lucky' class='star' type='checkbox'>

<!--⭐} Set a [for] attribute with the value of checkbox #id-->
<label for='lucky' class='star'></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, worth noting that in addition to the `f005` solid star, FontAwesome has unicode `f006` which is an empty star. This is true at least in the version I am using.