# FontAwesome with JS Kit ::before pseudoclass not working?

Tags: font-awesome-5

I can't get the icon to show up and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

SASS:

```
p.wp-caption-text::before
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
    font-weight: 900
    content: "\f030"
```

I've tried Font Awesome Regular/ Solid as well as different font-weights or different icons.
This is a camera icon, that is part of the Free icons.

The kit JS file (Created 3 days ago) is loading, as is the min.css

This is confirmed because icons that are in the HTML as

```
 <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
```

are showing up fine.

Edit: Confirmed bug which no doubt will be fixed soon, AND 
you need to add `data-search-pseudo-elements` for pseudo-elements to work

```
  <script data-search-pseudo-elements defer src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 5 replacement on <li> tag shows empty square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753688/font-awesome-5-replacement-on-li-tag-shows-empty-square)

Comment: ^ let me know if the duplicate is working

Comment: I this on GitHub too, and it's a bug! (my kit was loading CSS that used the Pro font while I'm on Free. And/but you were correct in that you also need to add data-search-pseudo-elements to the script call, thanks!)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cerensimsek1984/bpod30xz/6/  i found the problem..