# What is the difference between Use Font-awesome all.js and all.css?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have to use font awesome in my Web, and I found that I have 2 ways to implements Font Awesome.

I want to work with 5.0.1 version, I realized that using ALL.CSS allows me to use Font-awesome in classes with: AFTER in CSS, but beyond that I do not know what the difference is, and what each one is used for, and another question, when I should use both.

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
```

I hope to use the lightest font-awesome to implement

Comment: you should never use both. The only difference is that one is a Font and the other is SVG

Comment: and you can use pseudo element with the JS version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48753688/8620333

Comment: I use **defer "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js** I cant use pseudo element. In version 5.01 doesnt work?

Comment: you can, read the above link and consider using the last version .. .the 5.0 is very old, we are at 5.9 now

Answer (score 2):

`all.css` is the font version of FontAwesome.

When you need the SVG font, you have to use `js.css` version.

More detail can be found [on their website](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Choose the javaScript (.js) OR the css (.css) version, not both.

.js : Retrieves the `<i>` tags with class name `fa` and replaces them with the code from an **svg image**. This is a good option if you don't have a lot of Font Awesome icons on your web page.

.css : Loads the Font Awesome **font family** *(for example v5.0.1 = 37.78 kB)*. This is a good option when you have a **large number** of icons on your web page.