# FontAwesomeIcon (React) doesn't work with pseudoelements

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome, pseudo-element, font-awesome-5

I use FontAwesomeIcon component for ReactJS and finally was able to make it work...

But now there is another problem. Because from my understanding, FontAwesomeIcon is not an actual font, it's rather a component for rendering svg icons, how to use it if I need to specify an icon as content for pseudoelements? For example here, something like that worked:

```
.box::before {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    color: #ffffff;
    content: '\F05A';
}
```

But now it's not working. Should I install Fontawesome fonts too? If so, what's the point to FontAwesomeIcon component if I need both?

Comment: I guess the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753896/8620333 but I don't know how to adapt it the ReactJS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it and it worked... but it's insane, to be honest :((

Comment: at least it worked ;)